# GLSL UV (vec2) coords Optimised-out

Tags: opengl, glsl, uv-mapping

I'm writing an application using OpenGL 4.3 and GLSL and I need the shader to do basic UV mapping. The problem is that GLSL compiler seems to be optimising-out  the UV coordinates. I cannot access them from the application side of things.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 projection;

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 uvCoord;

out vec2 texCoord;

void main(void)
{
    texCoord = uvCoord;
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main(void)
{
    color = texture2D(tex, texCoord);
}
```

Both the vertex and fragment shader compile and link without errors, but when I call the attributes using the following code:

```
GLint effectPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(effect->getEffect(), "position");
GLint effectUVLocation = glGetAttribLocation(effect->getEffect(), "uvCoord");
```

I get the 0 for the `position` and -1 for the `uvCoord`, so I can only assume that the `uvCoord` has been optimised out even though I am using it to pass it from the vertex shader to the fragment shader.

The result is that the geometry is displayed but only in black, no texture mapping.

I have Written similar applications in Direct3D and HLSL with no problem of attributes being optimised out. I'm thinking that it is something simple that I am forgetting or not doing but have not found out what.

Comment: Why do you have two vertex shaders?  Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @genpfault Looks like a typo; the second shader looks like a fragment shader.

Comment: the source looks right, and the variable should not have been optimized out. Are you shure getEffect() gives you the correct program object?

Comment: And you're completely sure that the fragment shader compiles? It shouldn't. `texture2D()` is not a built-in function in the core profile. It's just `texture()`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 'texture2D'  with 'texture', and your attribute will be used.

Bad GLSL compiler: it should not compile your shader since texture2D is not available in core profile.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: You may have forgotten to call `glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);` after setting your `glVertexAttribPointers`.

Comment: gl_TexCoord doesn't exist in version 330 core